# Which bands or channels these NOAA AVHRR satellite images involve?

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, multi-band, noaa

These two satellite images are from NOAA AVHRR, but I do not know which bands or channels exactly both images represent.

Can you tell me the band or channels that are involved?

[image]

Comment: For the band numbers, see for example http://noaasis.noaa.gov/NOAASIS/ml/avhrr.html

Comment: thank you for reply, but would like to know why the water appear white close to gray in the image on the right while it appear close to dark?? do u think because the thermal infrared band??!

Comment: Probably - you will need to check the metadata to understand what the band numbers refer to in your case.

Comment: If you don't have metadata on the source image with the band number, could you provide more information like the date of acquisition and a print screen of the other bands ?